# How does the AFNetworking client decide when to disconnect during a POST operation

Tags: php, ios, json, client-server, afnetworking

I want to optimize my connection time during an afnetworking Post session. I use afnetworking to post from iOS to a server running PHP, and it receives a json confirmation message. The confirmation message happens instantly, but a lot of processing occurs on the data, I'm just wondering if the afnetworking has to stay connected the entire time, or if it disconnects as soon as it sees the json printout that it is looking for.

Comment: A POST completes when the response is received from the server or a timeout occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "optimize your connection time". If you are using something like the following...

```
//Call the request
[myManager POST:kMyEndpoint parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    //Do processing work here

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    //Error handling here
}];
```

...and you're doing your processing in the success block, that has nothing to do with the AFNetworking library. Essentially what happens is you pass in a block of code as the `success` parameter, and that block of code runs when AFNetworking gets a success message. That being said, even if your processing took 5 minutes (let's dearly hope not) and you lose internet connectivity, that's not going to affect the request since its success/failure block has already been called.

Sidenote: If you're doing CPU intensive work that will take more than a split second, you should do it asynchronously using GCD or the like so as not to pause the main thread/UI.

Comment: or consider subclassing NSOperation for your processing needs if it is repetitive

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure I'm asking my question correctly. On the server side I generate a message print json_encode(array('message'=>'received'));  will this make afnetworking happy and it disconnects from the server?

Comment: @user3344717 If the processing occurs on your server, AFNetworking's request will persist until it receives a response or times out. If you're doing processing on the client side with the information returned, AFNetworking won't care, and will be done once it calls the success/failure block.